# Sum of two columns from two tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the sum of two columns, but it seems to be adding incorrectly. I have a temporary table #temp and another table called workHours.

In the #temp:

```
emplyID | hours | projID | date
2       |  3    |  5     | 2015-01-01
5       |  5    |  5     | 2015-03-02    
3       |  4    |  5     | 2015-06-02
9       |  3    |  5     | 2015-05-03
2       |  3    |  5     | 2015-01-01
5       |  5    |  5     | 2015-02-02
3       |  4    |  5     | 2015-06-02
9       |  3    |  5     | 2015-06-03
```

workHours Table:

```
emplyID | hours | projID | date
3       |  4    |  5     | 2015-06-02
9       |  3    |  5     | 2015-06-03
2       |  3    |  5     | 2015-01-01
5       |  5    |  5     | 2015-02-02
2       |  3    |  5     | 2015-01-01
5       |  5    |  5     | 2015-02-02     
3       |  4    |  5     | 2015-06-02
9       |  3    |  5     | 2015-06-03
```

This is what I tried:

```
select c.FirstName, a.employeeID, a.hours as workHours, b.hours as 
tempWorkHours, a.hours+b.hours as totalHours, a.date 
from workHours as a, #temp as b, employee as c
where a.employeeID=c.employeeID and a.employeeID=b.employeeID
```

However, this seems to be grabbing the first hour from the first table and adding it to every hour on the second table and then grabbing the second vice versa.

Expected results should be for example:

```
emplyID | hours
  2    |   12
  3    |   16
  5    |   20
  9    |   12
```

How could I fix this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the expected result ? and which DBMS

Comment: You are pulling from 3 tables but you only listed 2?

Comment: even the column names in your statement and in the tables listed are different

Comment: You shouldn't use implicit join style. Switch to explicit `join` syntax (it's standard since 1992!).

Comment: Try joining on date aswel and also did u checked row_number function to get distinct rows from second table ?

Comment: You join n:m instead of 1:n, switch to aggregation over a `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UNION ALL` instead of `INNER JOIN`

```
select emplyID,sum(totalHours)
From
(
select emplyID, 
       hours as totalHours
from workHours as a 
union all
select emplyID, 
       hours as totalHours
From #temp as b
) a
Group by emplyID
```

- [**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/WZPT4690)

Comment: My total hours are off in the 1000s from this query :(

Comment: You still need to join c with the date or its going to excessively join a -> c

Comment: @EastonBornemeier - How do you know Employee table has `date` in it. Logically it makes no sense to current context.. Why would someone store Work hour dates in employee table

Comment: Trying to logically make sense of the reason behind over joining--we weren't provided the format of that table I was black-boxing it

Comment: @vanillacoke9191 - check now.. added demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN using comma(,) produces Cartesian product which delays.

```
SELECT SUM(A.HOURS+B HOURS) FROM TEMP AS A  JOIN WORKTABLE AS B ON A.EMPID = B.EMPID
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a partial cross-join between `#temp` and `workHours`.  I suspect you'll want to do something like this:

```
select c.FirstName,
    a.employeeID,
    a.hours as workHours,
    b.hours as tempWorkHours,
    a.hours + b.hours as totalHours,
    a.date 
from workHours as a
    inner join #temp as b
        on  a.employeeID = b.employeeID
        and a.projID     = b.projID
        and a.date       = b.date
    inner join employee as c
        on  a.employeeID = c.employeeID
```

Now, I have no way of knowing exactly which fields need to join between `workHours` and `#temp`.  I also have no way of knowing if you need an outer join.  I'm also guessing at your desired output from your current query.

Finally, avoid using comma joins.  It's an old syntax that most people find harder to read.

Edit:  Based on your updated expected output, I'd try this:

```
select c.FirstName,
    a.employeeID,
    sum(a.hours + b.hours) as totalHours,
from workHours as a
    inner join #temp as b
        on  a.employeeID = b.employeeID
        and a.projID     = b.projID
        and a.date       = b.date
    inner join employee as c
        on  a.employeeID = c.employeeID 
group by a.employeeID,
    c.FirstName
```

Comment: The sum of the hours seem to be in the 1000s :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing join conditions

```
 SELECT
    c.FirstName,
    a.employeeID, 
    SUM(a.hours) as workHours, 
    SUM(b.hours) as tempWorkHours, 
    SUM(a.hours+b.hours) as totalHours, 
    a.date 
    FROM workHours as a
    OUTER JOIN #temp as b ON a.employeeID=b.employeeID AND a.date = b.date
    INNER JOIN employee as c ON a.employeeID=c.employeeID AND a.date = c.date
    GROUP BY a.employeeID
```

If your employee id's are not unique enough to make it so every column has a unique pairing, then add more join conditions.

**EDIT:** Furthered join conditions

Comment: This is still grabbing the first hour from the first table and adding it all to the hours on the second table, grabbing the second hour from the first table and adding it to the hours on the second table pattern. :[

Comment: @vanillacoke9191 I've edited my answer after seeing that you have multiple ID's in the same table and they are not acting as the primary key

Comment: There are also dates that are not the same on the first table and second table. =X

Comment: @vanillacoke9191 you should be able to fix this using OUTER JOIN instead... But I don't know the exact specs of your table so results are still iffy

Comment: Also needed sums on the other hours fields oops

Comment: It's adding the total sum correctly, but the sum(a.hours) and sum(b.hours) are in the 1000s for some reason?

Comment: I mean, it's adding the sums in the 1000's as total hours correctly. So like 1000 + 1000 = 2000. Weird.

Comment: Try to do the same query without the join to c or anything to do with c at all and see if you get the same result--I don't know what sort of fields that table has to offer